# Finding optimal feature using Lasso regression in binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, regression

I am working on large data, and I want to find important features.
As I am a kind of biologist, so please forgive my lacking knowledge.

My dataset havs about 5000 attributes and 500 samples, which has binary classes 0 and 1. Also, the data set is biased - about 400 0s and 100 1s for samples.
I want to find some features, which influence most in determining class.

```
  A1   A2   A3  ... Gn Class
S1    1.0  0.8 -0.1 ... 1.0 0 
S2    0.8  0.4  0.9 ... 1.0 0
S3   -1.0 -0.5 -0.8 ... 1.0 1
...
```

As I got some advice from previous question, I am trying to find attribute coefficient of which are high as important features, using Lasso regression using L1 penalty, because it makes score of unimportant features to 0.

I am doing this work using scikit-learn library.

So, my questions are like this.

1. Can I use Lasso regression for **biased** binary class? If not, is it a good solution to use Logistic regression, although it does not use L1 penalty?
2. How can I find optimal value of alpha using LassoCV? The document says that LassoCV supports it, but I cannot find the function.
3. Is there other good way for this kind of classification?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a classifier instead of a regressor so either SVM or Logistic Regression would do the job. Instead you can use SGDClassifier where you can set the loss parameter to 'log' for Logistic Regression or 'hinge' for SVM.
In SGDClassifier you can set the penalty to either of 'l1', 'l2' or 'elasticnet' which is a combination of both.

You can find an opimum value of 'alpha' by either looping over different values of alpha and evaluating the performance over a validation set or you can use gridsearchcv as:

```
tuned_parameters = {'alpha': [10 ** a for a in range(-6, -2)]}
clf = GridSearchCV(SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='elasticnet',l1_ratio=0.15, n_iter=5, shuffle=True, verbose=False, n_jobs=10, average=False, class_weight='balanced')
                  , tuned_parameters, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')

#now clf is the best classifier found given the search space
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#you can find the best alpha here
print(clf.best_params_)
```

This, searches over the range of values of alpha you have provided in tuned_parameters and then finds the best one. You can change the performance criteria from 'f1_macro' to 'f1_weighted' or other metrics.

To address the skewness of your dataset in terms of labels use the class_weight parameter of [SGDCassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) and set it to "balanced".

To find the top 10 features contributing to the class labels you can find the indices as:

```
for i in range(0, clf.best_estimator_.coef_.shape[0]):
    top10 = np.argsort(clf.best_estimator_.coef_[i])[-10:]
```

Note 1: It is always good to keep some part of your dataset aside as validation/test set and after finding your optimum model evaluating it on the held out data.

Note 2: It is usually good to play a little bit with different types of feature normalisation and sample normalisation by dividing a row or a column to 'l2' or 'l1' of the row or column to see its effect on the performance using [normalizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

Note 3: For elasticnet regularisation play a little bit with l1_ratio parameter.

Comment: It seems to be a great help to me. I though that classification should be done after selecting good features(for dimension reduction), but SGDClassifier seems to do them once - so I don't need to consider feature selection and classification separately. Though I have never heard about the concept of SGD before, I'd like to try it. Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: The SGDClassifier cost function is equal to Logistic Regression and SVM depending on the loss parameter settings ('log' or 'hinge'). The only difference is that instead of updating the whole parameters of the model in SVM and LR it updates it gradually when it iterates over sample or batches of samples.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Feature selection is automatically done in supervised models by learning from labelled data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you don't mind, may I ask 1 more questions please?  Can I get N value of top-N features automatically(optimal N)? If it is Lasso, it makes score of unimportant features to 0, so I can remove them easily. Should I need process, such as RFE in this case?

Comment: clf.best_estimator_.coef is a matrix M x N where N is the number of features and M is the number of output classes which is 2 in your case. coef[i, j] is the importance of feature j in class i.  argsort(coef[i]) gives you the indices of features sorted by their importance (from low to high) in class i. the [-10:0] in the above code gives you the top 10 indices (the last ones).  Lasso is 'l1' regularisation so if you set penalty to 'l1' in the parameters it means you're using lasso which makes many of the weights in coef matrix zero. so just use 'l1' as penalty and use argsort for top features.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. But there is one thing I could not understand. Then, is it possible to find the list features which are used for classification by looking at coef? It may be a similar question, what I want to know is which features are actually selected for classification when test_X is given. Because I want to find some common character(biological meaning) of selected features, I want to find the result of feature selection, which seems to be automatically done. I am sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: coef[i] is a vector which has N dimension for each feature. Every feature has a weight in this vector which means how much that feature is important for identifying class i. So all the features are used except when the weight is zero. Using 'l1' regularisation (lasso) you can force many of these weights to become zero and only keep the best ones. The higher the coef[i,j], the more important feature j in identifying class i. So it's not like a feature is selected or not selected. The weights say how much each feature is selected.

Comment: Now I understood the process well. I misunderstood that only few important features may be selected and used for classification, so asked you the similar things many times. Thank you very much for kind explanation so far!

Comment: Note that the weights might be negative. For example if coef[i,j] is negative it means that if a sample has that feature j, it possibly doesn't belong to class i. So you'd expect a very negative feature coef[0, j] to be very positive in coef[1, j] because you have a binary classification.

Comment: Thank you for additional advice. I'd also check features with negative weights.